# find string from the file in somewhere

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to find a string from some file in subdirectory. 
Like 
we are in bundle/. 
and in bundle/ there are multiple subdirectories and multiple txt files
I want to do something like

```
  find . -type f -exec grep "\<F8\>" {} \;
```

want to get the file where it contain string < F8 >

this command does work, find the string, but never return filename
I hope anyone can give me a better solution to this, like display filename along with the line containing that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` by itself.

```
grep -r '<F8>' .
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -rl '<F8>' .
```

The `-r` option tells grep to search recursively through directories starting at `.`

The `-l` option tells it to show you just the filename that's matched, not the line itself.

Your output will look something like this:

```
./thisfile
./foo/bar/thatfile
```

If you want to limit this to only one file, append `| head -1` to the end of the line.

If you want output like:

```
./thisfile:My text contains the <F8> string
./foo/bar/thatfile:didn't remember to press the <F8> key on the
```

then you can just leave off the `-l` option.  Note that this output is not safe to parse, as filenames may contain colons, and colons in filenames are not escaped in grep's output.

Answer (score 0):

This should list out all the files and line numbers that match:

```
grep -nR '<F8>' *
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it's easier just to use `ack`. (`ack-grep` is the name used in Ubuntu's repos to keep from confusing it with another software with the same name.) It's available in most major repositories.

The command would be `ack -a "<F8>"` (or `ack-grep -a "<F8>"` in Ubuntu). The `-a` option is to search all file types.

Example:

**testfile**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
<F8>
<F9>
<F10>
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

**Output:**

```
$ ack -a "<F8>"
testfile
4:<F8>
```